# I am at a loss for why this is code is giving me a read acess violation. dereferencing pointer and subtracting another char should work in Theory

Tags: c, pointers, dereference, char-pointer

I dunno why this doesn't work. the code has a problem with the *c in 
charToInt function but should be a legal statement in c. at least so I thought. I am excited to learn something new here.

```
int charToint(char *c) {
    return *c - '0';  
}

int main(void) {
    char c = '3';
    printf("%d\n", charToint(c));
{
```

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: You are passing a `char`, but `charToint()` is expecting a pointer to `char`....

Comment: Fix your braces and actually pass a pointer, and tada! https://ideone.com/Xi9nle

Comment: Oh my gosh.  I feel dumb now.   yes your right, I am passing by value not by reference.  oh my. well that concept will probably never leave my brain every again.   Thank you all anyway.

Comment: No, the problem is that your question does not show the diagnostics issued by the compiler. Either you're using some really non-compliant compiler that issues no diagnostics for these or you've been ignoring them. `passing argument 1 of ‘charToInt’ makes pointer from integer without a cast` for example.

Comment: @RaymondChen wouldn't MSVC issue diagnostics for this by default?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala For C, this is warning C4047, enabled by default. But the project will still build and run, because it's just a warning, not an error. You have to look at the compiler output to see the warning.

Comment: I was using visual studio. it blew up at run time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a `char` to a function that expects a `char *`.  Your compiler should have warned you about this.  The value of that `char` is then interpreted as a pointer value and dereferenced.  Dereferencing an invalid pointer invokes undefined behavior, which in this case results in the program crashing.

The function is ultimately trying to work with a `char`, so change it to accept a `char`:

```
int charToint(char c) {
    return c - '0';  
}
```

Alternately, you can leave the function as it and pass it a pointer:

```
printf("%d\n", charToint(&c));
```

Comment: I'm guessing this wouldn't handle multi-character constants to well (eg. `return *c - '22';`)?

Comment: How many characters do you think you are allowed to put between single quotes and still have it be a character-constant? (hint: one). If you want an *string-literal* (that can contain more than one char), the wrap it in *double-quotes*. (and note, a string literal should not be modified on the vast majority of systems)

Comment: Thank you for the time spent on this.  I realize what I did. past by value not by reverence. therefore the function is not seeing the char and is then attempting to access memory it doesnt have.

Comment: @teaNcode Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: I clicked on the link you gave me, is that all I have to do to accept an answer??

Comment: @teaNcode The link tells you *how* to accept an answer.  Click the green check next to the answer you want to mark.